# C# - Store Column data in a List, during Foreach

Tags: c#, loops, selenium-webdriver, foreach

I am currently automating an app and there is this Web Table, I need to retrieve the information for a specific column, and store it in a list.

Currently I'm able to loop through all the rows of the list, and in each row, Im able to loop through all the columns.

The column looks like this:

```
    ID26        Credit      client1     10/10/2020      $2,222.00       $1,111.00       $1,111.00       $0.00       
    ID27        Credit      client1     10/10/2020      $3,434.00       $2,121.00       $1,313.00       $0.00       
    ID28        Credit      client1     10/10/2020      $4,543.00       $2,232.00       $2,311.00       $0.00       
    ID29        Credit      client1     10/10/2020      $5,434.00       $2,787.00       $2,647.00       $0.00       
    ID30        Credit      client1     10/10/2020      $6,178.00       $3,298.00       $2,880.00       $0.00       
    ID31        Credit      client1     10/10/2020      $7,398.00       $875.00         $6,523.00       $0.00       
    ID235       Credit      client1     10/10/2020      $10,000.00      $2,000.00       $8,000.00       $0.00
```

I've written this method, to retrieve the information:

```cs
public static void GetColumnValues()
{
    // xpath of html table
    var elemTable = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/main/div/div[2]/div[1]/table[2]/tbody"));

    // Fetch all Row of the table
    List<IWebElement> lstTrElem = new List<IWebElement>(elemTable.FindElements(By.TagName("tr")));
    String strRowData = "";
    List<String> ColumnValues = new List<String>();

    int RowsCounter = lstTrElem.Count();
    Console.WriteLine("Rows are: " + RowsCounter);

    // Traverse each row
    foreach (var elemTr in lstTrElem)
    {
        // Fetch the columns from a particuler row
        List<IWebElement> lstTdElem = new List<IWebElement>(elemTr.FindElements(By.TagName("td")));

        if (lstTdElem.Count > 0)
        {
            // Traverse each column
            foreach (var elemTd in lstTdElem)
            {
                // Tagname for the Posting Amount Column
                var PostingAmountCol = Driver.FindElements(By.TagName("td"))[5];

                // "\t\t" is used for Tab Space between two Text
                strRowData = strRowData + elemTd.Text + "\t\t";
                ColumnValues.Add(PostingAmountCol.Text);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // To print the data into the console
            Console.WriteLine("This is Header Row");
            Console.WriteLine(lstTrElem[0].Text.Replace(" ", "\t\t"));
        }
        Console.WriteLine(strRowData);
        strRowData = String.Empty;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(ColumnValues[0]);
    Console.WriteLine(ColumnValues[1]);
    Console.WriteLine(ColumnValues[2]);
    Console.WriteLine(ColumnValues[3]);
    Console.WriteLine(ColumnValues[4]);
    Console.WriteLine(ColumnValues[5]);
    Console.WriteLine(ColumnValues[6]);
}
```

The thing is that, after I run it, Instead of retrieving and storing all the values from the column [5], it only stores the value of the first row, and it stores it again, the very same value ("$2,222.00") for all the loops, and the output looks like this:

```
$2,222.00
$2,222.00
$2,222.00
$2,222.00
$2,222.00
$2,222.00
$2,222.00
```

I'm not sure why this is happening, is there a better (or easier) way, to complete the list with the data from the 6th column?

Comment: would you mind posting raw html, how it would look like, something wrong from this line `List<IWebElement> lstTdElem = new List<IWebElement>(elemTr.FindElements(By.TagName("td")));`

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something then. Does `Driver.FindElements(By.TagName("td"))[5];` return different elemets on each iteration?

Comment: @RufusL , what I tried to do, was to create a list, with all the rows of the table. Then I go through each of those rows, creating a list with all the columns exosting in that row. In the second loop, "postingamountcol" should find the value for the 6th column. In the first loop, 1st row, 6th column. in the second loop, 2nd row, 6th column (since the XPath will be /tr[1]/td[5], and the second loop (second row) will be /tr[2]/td[5]. If the identifier only defines td[5], it should add the value of the 6th column, in each row (loop). At least that's what I've trying to do.

Comment: I guess I don't know anything about selenium, so that's why I'm confused, but it seems to me that if you have the row data in `elemTr`, and you have the column data for that row in `lstTdElem`, then can't you just skip the inner loop and do: `if (lstTdElem.Count > 5) ColumnValues.Add(lstTdElem[5].Text);`?

Comment: Yes, that actually worked, Thanks @RufusL!!!